# How do I script procedures when generating a script with the SMO scripter?

Tags: sql-server, powershell, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, smo

I am trying to write a Powershell script to generate a SQL script that creates the stored procedures in my database.  Here is what I have:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO')| out-null

Function to-array ($c)
{
    foreach($item in $c)
    {
      $result += @($item)
    }
    $result
}

$s = new-object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server') "LOCALHOST"
$scrp = new-object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Scripter') ($s)
$dbs = $s.Databases
$fa = $dbs["FinancialAid"]

$scrp.Options.ScriptData = $True
$scrp.Options.AllowSystemObjects = $False
$scrp.Options.FileName = 'StoredProcedures.sql'
$scrp.Options.ToFileOnly = $True

# Finally the stored procedures

$sparray = to-array($fa.StoredProcedures)
$scrp.EnumScript($sparray)
```

This fails with the error:

```
Exception calling "EnumScript" with "1" argument(s): "Script failed for Server 'LOCALHOST'. "
At H:\Visual Studio 2012\FinancialAidApplication\Financial Aid Application\FinancialAidApplication\main\src\FinancialAidApp
\SQL-Scripts\sp.ps1:28 char:17
+ $scrp.EnumScript <<<< ($sparray)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

Looking at the output file, I see that it does have my stored procedures at the beginning, which is great, but then it has a bunch of system procedures.  The last one is `sys.sp_fulltext_table`.

As I already specified `$scrp.Options.AllowSystemObjects = $False` I don't understand why these system procedures are being included.  I would like to get rid of the system procedures and the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you could just skip the array completely and just use the pipeline.
(From a piece of something I use regularly but modified you use your variables)

```
add-type -AssemblyName "Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"
$s= new-object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server -ArgumentList 'LOCALHOST'
$fa = $s.Databases['FinancialAid']
   $scrp = New-Object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Scripter")
   $scrp.Server = $s
   $options = New-Object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.ScriptingOptions")
   $options.IncludeHeaders = $true
   $options.FileName = 'C:\temp\StoredProcedures.sql'
   $options.AppendToFile = $true
   $options.ToFileOnly = $true
   $options.ScriptBatchTerminator = $true
   $scrp.Options = $options
$fa.StoredProcedures | foreach {if ($_.IsSystemObject -eq $false) { $scrp.Script($_) }}
```

Comment: One thing: I had to use `$scrp.EnumScript` because `$scrp.Script` refuses to script "data" (and I guess it considers procedure bodies data).

Comment: @SamuelEdwinWard, are you saying you had to modify my example to get it to work?  If so I'm confused.  With a change of server and database name to the code above it worked without issue before I added it as an answer.

Comment: You're right, what you have should work.  I had set `ScriptData` to true and I shouldn't have.  It must have been a mistake I made while I was struggling with this earlier.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things

1. Try to get to the actual exception. Throw "inner exception powershell" into your favorite search engine. Right now, it's just a generic "something went wrong", which is hard to diagnose (both for you and for us!).
2. Try `$sparray = to-array($fa.StoredProcedures | where {$_.IsSystemObject -eq $false)`