# PowerShell to Script Out SQL Server Agent Jobs

Tags: powershell, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to create a PowerShell script (based on two examples found on blogs) that will take a list of servers in a file passed in as an argument and then script out the SQL Server Agent jobs into T-SQL.

I'm getting this error on the last line:
    $scrp.Script($job)

OBJECT DEFINITIONS

```
$scrp = new-object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Scripter') ($ServerName)
$job in $s.JobServer.Jobs
$s = new-object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server') $ServerName
```

ERROR:

> Exception calling "Script" with "1" argument(s): "Script failed for Job 'AX_Project_Contract_Monitor'. " At C:\Users\045810dl\Documents\PowerShell\Script Out SQL Agent Jobs\Script Out SQL Agent Jobs.ps1:101 char:6
>   +         $scrp.Script($job)
>   +         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FailedOperationException

The object $scrp seems to be correctly connected to the SMO.Scripter method based on debugging output.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Oops, forgot to include the PasteBin link to the full script:  https://pastebin.com/XUFtEW44

Comment: it look like its failing when it runs the `AX_Project_Contract_Monitor` job according to the error. Have you checked to make sure the SQL job runs properly?

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19383091/how-do-i-script-procedures-when-generating-a-script-with-the-smo-scripter has two suggestions: 1. Get the inner exception so you know whats _really_ happening. 2. Make sure `ScriptData` is false. I also suggest you make absolutely certain that you have access to the output folder. But innerexception should tell you exactly what the issue is

Comment: I took the advice of Nick.McDermaid and got the inner exception information.  That helped tremendously!  Getting the actual error message made it simple to fix.  I determined there was a problem with the path in $jobfilename.  I switched to using an absolute path and then it worked!  Thanks so much!